# How to get the property of an object from text file by passing an object using C# selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have implemented to get the property of an object in Java with selenium webdriver it's working fine.
But,
Is there any way to get the property of an object from text file using C# with Selenium webdriver

Here is my code which I have written using Java with Selenium Webdriver

```
    String Path_OR = Constants.Path_OR;
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(Path_OR);
    OR= new Properties(System.getProperties());
    OR.load(fs);
```

Can anyone suggest the C# with Selenium Webdriver code to get the property of an object.

text file contains

```
proUsrName=.//*[@id='txtUserName']
```

My requirement is when I pass the 'Object' to the text file then, it should be returned the property of that particular object.

For Example: If I pass the 'proUsrName' to the method, it should be return

`'.//*[@id='txtUserName']'`.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does this text file look like ? What does `getProperties()` look like ?

Comment: text file looks like

proUsrName=.//*[@id='txtUserName']
proPassword=.//*[@id='txtPassword']
prologinbtn=.//*[@id='BtnLogin']
prologinform=.//*[@id='form1']/section/div[4]/section/div[2]
prologinfailuremsg=.//*[@id='lblFailure']

My requirement is when I pass the 'Object' to the text file then, it should be returned the property of that particular object.
For Example: If I pass the 'proUsrName' to the method, it should be return './/*[@id='txtUserName']'.